# Flutterのble_peripheralライブラリを使用してble writeをするには

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

[ble_peripheralライブラリ](https://github.com/rohitsangwan01/ble_peripheral)のexampleコードを使用して，central側からBLE Writeができるように改良を試みてるのですが，以下のログが表示されwriteができません．[exampleコード](https://github.com/rohitsangwan01/ble_peripheral/tree/main/example/lib)のhome_controller.dartのBleService get _batteryServiceの部分を変更して実行しています．コードを載せますので，修正すべき箇所をご教授お願いいたします．central側は[flutter_blue_plusライブラリ](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus/versions)のexampleコードを使用してwriteしようとしています．

```
D/[FBP-Android]( 3111): [FBP] onMethodCall: writeCharacteristic
D/[FBP-Android]( 3111): [FBP] onMethodCall: getAdapterState
W/BluetoothGattServer( 3111): Unhandled exception in callback
W/BluetoothGattServer( 3111): java.lang.RuntimeException: Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread. Current thread: binder:3111_6
W/BluetoothGattServer( 3111):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.ensureRunningOnMainThread(FlutterJNI.java:1449)
W/BluetoothGattServer( 3111):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.dispatchPlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:1070)
W/BluetoothGattServer( 3111):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.send(DartMessenger.java:282)
W/BluetoothGattServer( 3111):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartExecutor$DefaultBinaryMessenger.send(DartExecutor.java:470)
W/BluetoothGattServer( 3111):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartExecutor.send(DartExecutor.java:223)
W/BluetoothGattServer( 3111):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.BasicMessageChannel.send(BasicMessageChannel.java:106)
W/BluetoothGattServer( 3111):   at com.rohit.ble_peripheral.BleCallback.onWriteRequest(BlePeripheral.g.kt:490)
W/BluetoothGattServer( 3111):   at com.rohit.ble_peripheral.BlePeripheralPlugin$gattServerCallback$1.onCharacteristicWriteRequest(BlePeripheralPlugin.kt:405)
W/BluetoothGattServer( 3111):   at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattServer$1.onCharacteristicWriteRequest(BluetoothGattServer.java:228)
W/BluetoothGattServer( 3111):   at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattServerCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattServerCallback.java:186)
W/BluetoothGattServer( 3111):   at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1285)
W/BluetoothGattServer( 3111):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1244)
```

```
  BleService get _batteryService {
return BleService(
  uuid: serviceBattery,
  primary: true,
  characteristics: [
    BleCharacteristic(
      uuid: characteristicBatteryLevel,
      properties: [
        CharacteristicProperties.read.index,
        CharacteristicProperties.notify.index,
        CharacteristicProperties.write.index
      ],
      value: null,
      permissions: [AttributePermissions.readable.index,
                    AttributePermissions.writeable.index
                  ],
    ),
  ],
);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ble_peripheralのgithub issuesを見ると同じような問題が上がってます。

その対応がpullリクエストまで行ってるので、マージされるのを待つか、リクエスト発行側のフォークの修正版を使うのはどうでしょうか。

Comment: すみません，修正版があることに気づいていませんでした．修正版で試したところ，BLE Writeができました．この度はありがとうございました．